# how to solve $x^2 \frac{dy}{dx}=y^2\frac{dx}{dy}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If I separate variables, I get factors of $dx^2,dy^2$ which keep me stuck. And if I treat $\frac{dx}{dy}$ as $x'$ (or with $y$), then I can't solve the resulting integral $\int \frac{x'dx}{x^2}$.

Some hints would be wonderful as I feel I have exhausted all possibilities I can think of. Wolfram Alpha, ChatGPT, Google don't help me. The solution should be for $y(1)=1$: $y=x,y=\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: How do you relate $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y}$? That's a good place to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: let $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$. You can rewrite the equation as $(y')^2-(\frac{y}{x})^2=0$ or $(y'-\frac{y}{x})(y'+\frac{y}{x})=0$

Answer (score 1):

$x^2(dy/dx)=y^2(dx/dy)$

$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{dy/dx}$

$x^2(dy/dx)^2=y^2$

From here there are options.

$[x(dy/dx)-y][x(dy/dx)+y]=0\implies dy/dy=dx/x\implies y=kx$

Or $dy/y=-dx/x\implies \ln y=-\ln x +c\implies y=c/x $

You could also take the square root

$x(dy/dx)=\pm y\implies dy/y=\pm dx/x$

Answer (score 0):

From inspiration by a comment from someone that has now been removed by someone: Actually the squared factors $dx^2$ and $dy^2$ if you combine them with $\frac{1}{x^2}$ and $\frac{1}{y^2}$, that leads easily to the solution.